# Adapting Interfaces for Moq unittest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have run into a problem with a project where we have issues with some third party classes. The problem is that we cannot instantiate the classes from the third party, because we only get metadata representations, but we can fix that by an adapter pattern. The problem is the class that we need to unit test implements third-party interfaces:

```
public class OurClass: ThirdPartyInterface
{

}
```

These interfaces return third-party classes (the ones we can wrap via the adapter pattern) but they get returned as the original. So we need to somehow create some sort of adapter interface system.

Our best idea so far is to create a class (FacadeThirdParty) that implements the ThirdpartyInterface, then wrap the third-party classes coming from the interface (TPClass) into an adapter class (TPClassAdapter) and then send it through our own interface (IFacadeThirdPartyInterface) that "OurClass" implements:

[image: Diagram over our best idea]

This way we can Moq our IFacadeThirdPartyInterface and adapter class interfaces, and not be bothered by the third party. Is this idea any good? I feel there might be a better way to do this.

**UPDATE: New proposed solution**

So after some thoughts and what has been said in comments, I think I have a new solution that will work:

[image]

The issue I had, which I might not have explained very well was that the callback functions that were used by the third-party system. So, what I've done here is that we have "OurClass" that I need to unit test. It will now talk to a Facade layer and get callbacks through the IFacadeCallback interface. All third-party interfaces will be implemented in the facade class. When one of these interfaces executes a call to the facade, it will redirect it through the IFacadeCallback facade. If the call has Third party classes, it will wrap them in an adapter class and return the interface of that class (ITPClass). This should, in theory, isolate "OurClass" so I can use Moq to test its functions.

Comment: completely abstract the 3rd party dependency out of the equation. Tightly coupling to concerns you have no control over make things difficult, as you have seen.

Comment: @Nkosi So something like the new solution I have updated the post with? Was that what you were thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is instead of using the adaptor pattern, I would be injecting the dependency on the third party into the class you want to test e.g.

```
public class OurClass
{
    public OurClass(IThirdPartyInterface thirdParty)
    {
        _thirdParty = thirdParty;
    }
    private readonly IThirdPartyInterface _thirdParty;
}
```

And the interface `IThirdPartyInterface` would be a simple interface with the Method/Properties that you require in your code from the `ThirdPartyInterface` class.

Doing it this way you can easily mock the dependencies this class has, plus this also builds upon the Dependency inversion principle.

Comment: I think I see where you are going, but the problem here is that I can mock the IThirdPartyInterface, but I can't mock or instantiate any third party classes the interface needs or return.

Comment: In this case I would say you are not Unit Testing, If you want to test the third party's implementation then you would be performing integration tests. What you should be doing is mocking out the interfaces method and return's so you can unit test your code without worrying about the implementation of the third party

Comment: Ohh I'm not trying to test the third party at all. They are the communication entities. I thought I could use them to input some data in them and send them to my class via the Mocked third-party interface and make sure the code in "OurClass" is handling it correctly. However, I can't instantiate any third-party class. So, I need to make adapters for third-party classes and make some system with the third-party interfaces so they don't return the third-party classes but returns my adapter classes. Which means I need the have a layer between the third-party interfaces and "OurClass"